# My <TR> keeps going full browser width instead of the 600pixels of my Table

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, tablerow

It has been a while since I had to code an email, but the regular is on holiday so they
asked me the designer to fix it.

I need a Block to be repeated 3 times with a TR separator to create some structure.

However when I use the separator it keeps going full browser width and not the 600 Pixels I gave as max width. Maybe I'm just overlooking something or maybe it is a technical point I don't see.

[image: Image of my error]

```html
<body style="HEIGHT: 100% !important; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,sans-serif !important; WIDTH: 100% !important; FONT-WEIGHT: 400; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px !important; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 0px !important; PADDING-LEFT: 0px !important; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px !important; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f8f8f8; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"
  bgColor=#ffffff>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
      }
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        line-height: 40px;
      }
      .mobile-table {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: auto;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:601px) {
      .email-container {
        width: 600px !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        width: 30%;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: 20px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:601px) {
      .email-container {
        width: 600px !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        width: 30%;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: 20px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:601px) {
      .footer-width1 {
        width: 10%;
      }
      .footer-width3 {
        width: 10%;
      }
      .footer-width2 {
        width: 80%;
      }
    }
    
    body,
    table,
    td,
    p,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    a,
    td,
    tr {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    }
  </style>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;margin:0 auto;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;table-layout:fixed">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <![endif]-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;margin:auto;max-width:600px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" class="email-container">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#fff;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="mobile-table" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                    <tbody>
                      <TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f8f8f8;">
                        <TD align=center>
                          <P style="FONT-SIZE: 10px">
                            <%@ include view='agpb_yongo_viewInBrowser' %>
                          </P>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                      <TR>
                        <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #00b3ba 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" bgColor=#ffffff align=left>
                          <TABLE style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse !important; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=center border=0>
                            <TBODY>
                              <TR>
                                <TD class=mobile-center style="-MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" vAlign=top align=<left>
                                  <a href="https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__www.yongo.be_fr-2DBE_-3Futm-5Fmedium-3Demail-26utm-5Fsource-3Dnewsletter-26utm-5Fcampaign-3Dgeneral-2Dheader-2Dfooter-2Dcampaigns-2Dfr&d=DwMGAg&c=umdN7-UKVWbf7Ie0PtI_qgdqHn0WRecdD9KiIHWQsvs&r=HQRgOZ8X3BUQucU6tPFihn9ywRTa8IAu20X7OO1wNb0&m=SQUpDEKoBLo3BVZvLyRWVRJNd4pB7LTpOe_B9giP5Qc&s=7cS77afvbCiLLIV3eFvbvwoMyP1wCY5Hn0vuh_kbLwI&e="></left>
                                    <IMG style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; TEXT-DECORATION: none; HEIGHT: auto; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; OUTLINE-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; -MS-INTERPOLATION-MODE: bicubic; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" alt=Logo src="https://portal.yongo.be/Images/Yongo_logo_Email_Header.png"
                                      width=110 height=30> </a>
                                </TD>
                              </TR>
                            </TBODY>
                          </TABLE>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0px 0px 0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="mobile-center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;text-align:center"> <img alt="birthday banner" src="images/header-welcome-fr.jpg" width="600" style="max-width: 100% !important;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:0;display:block;outline:0;text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;"
                                  /> </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:660px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" align="center">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#333;font-size:28px;color:#333333;line-height:22px;margin:0;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:30px 10px 6px 10px;letter-spacing: 2px;
    " class="body-text">
                                  <p style="margin:0; font-weight:300;color:#fda200;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:20px;"> F&eacute;licitations ! </p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#333;font-size:16px;color:#333333;line-height:22px;margin:0;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0px 12% 6px 12%" class="body-text">
                                  <p style="margin:0;color: #4d4d4d; "> Bonjour {perso&lt;FirstName&gt;}, </p>
                                  <p> Merci d&rsquo;avoir rejoint Yongo. Votre compte a &eacute;t&eacute; cr&eacute;&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s. <strong>Il ne vous reste plus qu&rsquo;une &eacute;tape pour finaliser votre inscription.</strong> Faites votre
                                    choix et commencez votre exp&eacute;rience Yongo ! </p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:660px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="center">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:25%; vertical-align:top;padding-top:25px;">
                                <p><img src="images/parents.png" width="70%" height="auto" alt="create project image" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" /></p>
                              </td>
                              <td style=" color: #333333;text-align:left;padding-top:45px;">
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px;font-size:22px;color:#0d999e;font-weight:bold;">Je cr&eacute;e un Yongo en tant que parent</p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px">En tant que parent, ouvrez d&egrave;s maintenant un Yongo pour votre enfant et commencez &agrave; pr&eacute;parer son avenir financier. </p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <ul style="list-style:none;padding:0;">
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Choisissez Yongo Moon ou Yongo Star</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">10 &euro; suffisent pour activer votre plan</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Montant et fr&eacute;quence des versements au choix</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Ajoutez gratuitement Yongo Dreams</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Apprenez &agrave; votre enfant &agrave; se familiariser avec l&rsquo;argent</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p align="left" class="m_-2233460256086911310button-width" style="background-color:#fda200;border:1px solid #fda200;border-radius:3px;display:block;margin:0;margin-top:30px;text-align:center;height:55px;width:325px"> <a href="https://www.yongo.be/nl-be/beleggen-sparen-voor-kind?utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=babyboom-20180517-nl" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:18px;text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:18px 17px;"
                                    target="_blank"><strong>J&rsquo;ouvre un Yongo pour mon enfant &gt;</strong></a> </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:25px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:600px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="center">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:25%; vertical-align:top;padding-top:25px;">
                                <p><img src="images/parents.png" width="70%" height="auto" alt="create project image" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" /></p>
                              </td>
                              <td style=" color: #333333;text-align:left;padding-top:45px;">
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px;font-size:22px;color:#0d999e;font-weight:bold;">Je cr&eacute;e un Yongo en tant que parent</p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px">En tant que parent, ouvrez d&egrave;s maintenant un Yongo pour votre enfant et commencez &agrave; pr&eacute;parer son avenir financier. </p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <ul style="list-style:none;padding:0;">
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Choisissez Yongo Moon ou Yongo Star</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">10 &euro; suffisent pour activer votre plan</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Montant et fr&eacute;quence des versements au choix</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Ajoutez gratuitement Yongo Dreams</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Apprenez &agrave; votre enfant &agrave; se familiariser avec l&rsquo;argent</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p align="left" class="m_-2233460256086911310button-width" style="background-color:#fda200;border:1px solid #fda200;border-radius:3px;display:block;margin:0;margin-top:30px;text-align:center;height:55px;width:325px"> <a href="https://www.yongo.be/nl-be/beleggen-sparen-voor-kind?utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=babyboom-20180517-nl" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:18px;text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:18px 17px;"
                                    target="_blank"><strong>J&rsquo;ouvre un Yongo pour mon enfant &gt;</strong></a> </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:25px 0"></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>

                      <TR>
                        <TD align=center>
                          <P style="FONT-SIZE: 10px">
                            <%@ include view='agpb_yongo_unsubscribe' %>
                          </P>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: your table is 100% width not 600px;

Comment: Try to stay away from using `!important` all the time. A future you or someone else who didn't write the code may not remember/realize it's there, making for a difficult fix later on.

Comment: Your table width is set to 100%, <tr> has same width as table

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#bodyTable {
  width: auto;
}
```

```css
#bodyTable {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body style="HEIGHT: 100% !important; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,sans-serif !important; WIDTH: 100% !important; FONT-WEIGHT: 400; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px !important; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 0px !important; PADDING-LEFT: 0px !important; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px !important; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f8f8f8; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"
  bgColor=#ffffff>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
      }
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        line-height: 40px;
      }
      .mobile-table {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: auto;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:601px) {
      .email-container {
        width: 600px !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        width: 30%;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: 20px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:601px) {
      .email-container {
        width: 600px !important;
      }
      .footer-width {
        width: 30%;
      }
      .footer-height {
        width: 20px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:601px) {
      .footer-width1 {
        width: 10%;
      }
      .footer-width3 {
        width: 10%;
      }
      .footer-width2 {
        width: 80%;
      }
    }
    
    body,
    table,
    td,
    p,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    a,
    td,
    tr {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    }
  </style>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;margin:0 auto;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;table-layout:fixed">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <![endif]-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;margin:auto;max-width:600px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" class="email-container">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#fff;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="mobile-table" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                    <tbody>
                      <TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f8f8f8;">
                        <TD align=center>
                          <P style="FONT-SIZE: 10px">
                            <%@ include view='agpb_yongo_viewInBrowser' %>
                          </P>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                      <TR>
                        <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #00b3ba 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" bgColor=#ffffff align=left>
                          <TABLE style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse !important; -MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=center border=0>
                            <TBODY>
                              <TR>
                                <TD class=mobile-center style="-MS-TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0" vAlign=top align=<left>
                                  <a href="https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__www.yongo.be_fr-2DBE_-3Futm-5Fmedium-3Demail-26utm-5Fsource-3Dnewsletter-26utm-5Fcampaign-3Dgeneral-2Dheader-2Dfooter-2Dcampaigns-2Dfr&d=DwMGAg&c=umdN7-UKVWbf7Ie0PtI_qgdqHn0WRecdD9KiIHWQsvs&r=HQRgOZ8X3BUQucU6tPFihn9ywRTa8IAu20X7OO1wNb0&m=SQUpDEKoBLo3BVZvLyRWVRJNd4pB7LTpOe_B9giP5Qc&s=7cS77afvbCiLLIV3eFvbvwoMyP1wCY5Hn0vuh_kbLwI&e="></left>
                                    <IMG style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; TEXT-DECORATION: none; HEIGHT: auto; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; OUTLINE-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; -MS-INTERPOLATION-MODE: bicubic; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" alt=Logo src="https://portal.yongo.be/Images/Yongo_logo_Email_Header.png"
                                      width=110 height=30> </a>
                                </TD>
                              </TR>
                            </TBODY>
                          </TABLE>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0px 0px 0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="mobile-center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;text-align:center"> <img alt="birthday banner" src="images/header-welcome-fr.jpg" width="600" style="max-width: 100% !important;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:0;display:block;outline:0;text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;"
                                  /> </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:660px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0" align="center">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#333;font-size:28px;color:#333333;line-height:22px;margin:0;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:30px 10px 6px 10px;letter-spacing: 2px;
    " class="body-text">
                                  <p style="margin:0; font-weight:300;color:#fda200;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:20px;"> F&eacute;licitations ! </p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#333;font-size:16px;color:#333333;line-height:22px;margin:0;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0px 12% 6px 12%" class="body-text">
                                  <p style="margin:0;color: #4d4d4d; "> Bonjour {perso&lt;FirstName&gt;}, </p>
                                  <p> Merci d&rsquo;avoir rejoint Yongo. Votre compte a &eacute;t&eacute; cr&eacute;&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s. <strong>Il ne vous reste plus qu&rsquo;une &eacute;tape pour finaliser votre inscription.</strong> Faites votre
                                    choix et commencez votre exp&eacute;rience Yongo ! </p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:660px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="center">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:25%; vertical-align:top;padding-top:25px;">
                                <p><img src="images/parents.png" width="70%" height="auto" alt="create project image" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" /></p>
                              </td>
                              <td style=" color: #333333;text-align:left;padding-top:45px;">
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px;font-size:22px;color:#0d999e;font-weight:bold;">Je cr&eacute;e un Yongo en tant que parent</p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px">En tant que parent, ouvrez d&egrave;s maintenant un Yongo pour votre enfant et commencez &agrave; pr&eacute;parer son avenir financier. </p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <ul style="list-style:none;padding:0;">
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Choisissez Yongo Moon ou Yongo Star</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">10 &euro; suffisent pour activer votre plan</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Montant et fr&eacute;quence des versements au choix</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Ajoutez gratuitement Yongo Dreams</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Apprenez &agrave; votre enfant &agrave; se familiariser avec l&rsquo;argent</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p align="left" class="m_-2233460256086911310button-width" style="background-color:#fda200;border:1px solid #fda200;border-radius:3px;display:block;margin:0;margin-top:30px;text-align:center;height:55px;width:325px"> <a href="https://www.yongo.be/nl-be/beleggen-sparen-voor-kind?utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=babyboom-20180517-nl" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:18px;text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:18px 17px;"
                                    target="_blank"><strong>J&rsquo;ouvre un Yongo pour mon enfant &gt;</strong></a> </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:25px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse!important;max-width:600px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="center">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:25%; vertical-align:top;padding-top:25px;">
                                <p><img src="images/parents.png" width="70%" height="auto" alt="create project image" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" /></p>
                              </td>
                              <td style=" color: #333333;text-align:left;padding-top:45px;">
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px;font-size:22px;color:#0d999e;font-weight:bold;">Je cr&eacute;e un Yongo en tant que parent</p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <p style="MARGIN: 0px">En tant que parent, ouvrez d&egrave;s maintenant un Yongo pour votre enfant et commencez &agrave; pr&eacute;parer son avenir financier. </p>
                                <P style="MARGIN: 0px">&nbsp;</P>
                                <ul style="list-style:none;padding:0;">
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Choisissez Yongo Moon ou Yongo Star</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">10 &euro; suffisent pour activer votre plan</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Montant et fr&eacute;quence des versements au choix</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Ajoutez gratuitement Yongo Dreams</li>
                                  <li style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><img src="images/rooshart.jpg" width="8px" height="auto" alt="" style="padding-right:10px;">Apprenez &agrave; votre enfant &agrave; se familiariser avec l&rsquo;argent</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p align="left" class="m_-2233460256086911310button-width" style="background-color:#fda200;border:1px solid #fda200;border-radius:3px;display:block;margin:0;margin-top:30px;text-align:center;height:55px;width:325px"> <a href="https://www.yongo.be/nl-be/beleggen-sparen-voor-kind?utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=babyboom-20180517-nl" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:18px;text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:18px 17px;"
                                    target="_blank"><strong>J&rsquo;ouvre un Yongo pour mon enfant &gt;</strong></a> </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:25px 0"></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:5px 0"></td>
                      </tr>

                      <TR>
                        <TD align=center>
                          <P style="FONT-SIZE: 10px">
                            <%@ include view='agpb_yongo_unsubscribe' %>
                          </P>
                        </TD>
                      </TR>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the style mentioned above